# what does this define directive syntax mean?

Tags: c++, winapi, syntax, preprocessor-directive

These directives are part of a code and work. But I don't understand their syntax. I just know that "\" means the code continues next row. Can anybody help me? Why there is a";". What "ADDPOPUPMENU" means and why uppercase?

```
#define ADDPOPUPMENU(hmenu, string) \
HMENU hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu(); \
AppendMenu(hmenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hSubMenu, string);
// Add a menu item
#define ADDMENUITEM(hmenu, ID, string) \
AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, ID, string);
```

Comment: It's *line* continuation, not row. And it makes the whole macro be a single line.

Comment: `ADDPOPUPMENU` is the macro name, why uppercase, shrug ...

Comment: There's a ";" because the person defining the macro wanted the macro expansion to contain a ";". The name "ADDPOPUPMENU" is in uppercase because the person defining the macro wanted the macro name to be in uppercase.

Comment: Why is there a semicolon? Because C++ statements require semicolons? Anyway, uppercase macro naming is conventional so as to stand out as a macro.

Comment: @selim It's a couple of preprocessor macros with two and three parameters, respectively, that expand to some function calls using those parameters. That should be enough for you to work the rest out with your favourite search engine and/or your compiler's documentation.

Comment: I suggest you use the macros in some simple code, and then run the source through the preprocessor and look at the output from the preprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

The code is defining two separate macros:

```
#define ADDPOPUPMENU(hmenu, string) \
HMENU hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu(); \
AppendMenu(hmenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hSubMenu, string);
```

```
// Add a menu item
#define ADDMENUITEM(hmenu, ID, string) \
AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, ID, string);
```

Preprocessor `#define` statements are simply defining text substitutions.  So code like this:

```
ADDPOPUPMENU(MyMenu, "Name")
ADDMENUITEM(MyMenu, MyID, "Item")
```

Will be replaced with the following during the preprocessing stage before the compiling stage begins:

```
HMENU hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
AppendMenu(MyMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hSubMenu, "Name");
AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, MyID, "Item");
```